# Natural constructions (not depending on parameters)

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, graph-theory

Consider graph clusterings as a prototypical example of (logical) [constructions](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-construction/).

Let a [clustering](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mlsurveys/13.pdf) of a graph $(V,E)$ be any covering of $V$, i.e. a set $C$ with $\bigcup C = V$.

I am looking for a way to define the notion of a "*natural* graph clustering". By a natural graph clustering I mean - informally - a clustering that can be uniformly defined for all graphs by a formula or an algorithm that doesn't depend on arbitrary parameters.

Intended examples of natural graph clusterings include

1. the connected components of a graph
2. the cliques of a graph
3. the maximal cliques of a graph
4. the orbits of the automorphism group of a graph

Intended counter-examples (while depending on parameters) include

1. cliques up to size $k$
2. quasi-cliques, i.e. a fraction $\theta$ of the edges can be missing

But what does it mean *formally* to "depend on a parameter"? E.g. counter-example (1) can easily be defined by a formula not containing any numeric parameter $k$ but instead an appropriate number of quantifiers.

> (How) can the notion of "dependence on a parameter" be formalized?

The problem is: every number (or other distinguished set) occuring in a formula as a parameter can either be eliminated by an appropriate number of quantifiers or by a [definite description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_descriptions).

An intuitive feeling remains that the counter-examples are less "natural" than the intended examples.

> So what does distinguish the intended examples from the counter-examples?

Or is it a chimera, and such a distinction cannot be made?

**[Appendix]**

There are unclear cases for which I have no intuition whether they should count as examples or counter-examples:

1. connected induced subgraphs with more edges than vertices (a kind of quasi-clique)

---

<sup>I also tried to ask [this question at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679440/natural-definitions-of-families-of-subgraphs).</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure this is an appropriate question for MO, but even if it is you only waited 24 hours to get an answer on math.SE.  You should wait at least a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Andy: You are demanding a lot of patience. Experience taught me that when you don't get an answer at MSE - or even a comment - after a couple of hours, you will only get one by sheer accident.

Comment: @Andy: And please give me a slight hint: Is my question inappropriate because it is trivial or because it is nonsensical? (I cannot guess from the close votes, but maybe I would learn something from this information.)

Comment: @Hans: I have not voted to close, but your question feels a bit "stone soup-y" to me.  You are pitching out a very soft idea and asking whether and how it can be mathematically formalized.  Like almost every very soft idea: certainly, yes it can be mathematically formalized, in several different ways.  Whether or which of these formalizations will be preferable to you is hard to know in advance, so your are essentially asking for people to create some mathematics until you say you like it.  This site is designed for more focused questions than that.

Comment: I think that Pete's comment describes the issues with this question perfectly.  And I'm sorry if you feel like we demand patience here, but that is the generally agreed upon policy.  If you don't get a good answer on math.se, you should think about how to improve your question to get one rather than just copying it here.

Comment: @Pete: I will do my best to digest this "stony" answer which I really do appreciate. (What I don't understand immediately: Why you consider my idea *very* soft. Soft - OK. But *very* soft?)

Comment: @Pete: I don't want anyone to *create* some mathematics - I would be perfectly happy with a reference.

Comment: @Hans: I'd prefer to just take back the "very" if it makes you feel better.  But briefly, I think the "very" means: two people could give two reasonable formulations which have absolutely nothing in common.  So answering the question once is not necessarily any progress to a "real answer".

Comment: Hans, one idea for progress might be to articulate the differences between your somewhat vague parameter concept and the usual analysis of parameters in definitions that one finds (extensively) in first-order logic and model theory. The notions do not coincide, since in most cases one doesn't actually need the natural number parameter $k$ in the kinds of cases you are looking at, since one can build $k$ into the definition without talking explicitly about $k$. But the analysis of when and which parameters are needed for certain kinds of definability notions is highly developed.

Comment: Also, your question would benefit from a more formal treatment of definability: what is the formal language? What is the structure in which the definitions are interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

I guess somehow we should rule out spurious ways to depend on parameter, such as

> "a graph is *$k$-cliqueish* if either $k=1$ and the graph is connected,
>   or $k\ge 2$ and the graph has a clique of size $k$".

Here is attempt (not constructive and not really canonical). Fix a first-order language $L$ containing some basic arithmetic so we can use parameters from $\mathbb N$.

**Definition 1.** For an $L$-definable function $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$, define the *complexity* $C(f)$ to be the shortest definition of $f$ in $L$.

**Definition 2.** For functions $f^*$ and $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$, we say that $f$ is an *improvement* of $f^*$ if $C(f)\le C(f^*)$, and for all but finitely many $n$, $f(n)=f^*(n)$.

**Definition 3.** A set $S$ *depends on a parameter* if there exists an injective $f$ with domain $\mathbb N$, such that for all improvements $g$ of $f$, there is an $n$ with $f(n)=g(n)=S$. In this case we say the value of the parameter can be $n$.

**Theorem(?)** The collection $S$ of graphs having a clique of size 5 does depend on a parameter (which can have the value 5), since a natural definition of "*clique of size $k$*" cannot be shortened and modified in such a way as to still be correct for almost all $k$, and at the same time remove $S$ from the range.